# Kernel32 и LUA

Tags: lua, c++, kernel

Помогите перевести код из `c++` в `LUA`:

```
ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)0x00706D54, &lvl, 2, 0);
```

Попробовал в `LUA`:

```
a = DLL.CallFunction("kernel32.dll", "ReadProcessMemory", hProcess..", 7368020, "..lvl..", 2, 0", DLL_RETURN_TYPE_INTEGER, DLL_CALL_STDCALL);
```

где `hProcess-handle`, `lvl`-переменная `int`, но возвращается постоянно `0`.
Вся проблема в эмитации `&lvl` в `LUA`.

p.s. Это синтаксис `AutoPlay Media Studio`, которая работает на `LUA`.

Answer (score 4):

Решил проблему. Посмотрел в Delphi перед lvl стоит @. Значит нужна не переменная, а её адрес памяти в которую она записана. Я создал переменную в определённом адресе и дал функции её адрес. Всё работает!

Comment: [link text][1]


  [1]: http://img.1001mem.ru/posts/206000/205815.jpg